# How to navigate a Barbie in a grid system?

Tags: java, navigation

I'm trying to solve an interesting problem for navigating a Barbie doll inside a grid system. Initially, Barbie is in [0,0] position, means in the intersection of the X and Y axis. Barbie has 3 operations on movement with 'F' for forward, 'R' for right turn (90 degree) and 'L' for left turn (90 degree). Say, if I pass the direction String of "FF", the position should be [0,2]. I solve the problem and the current state of code is as following,

```
public static void barbiePosition(String str ){

    if( str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return;

    int [] initial = {0,0};

    boolean xPos = false, xNeg = false, yPos = true, yNeg = false; 

    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

    for( char c: ch){

        // the initial postion of the robot is towards the positive Y axis 

        if(c == 'L'){

            if(xPos){

                xPos = false;
                yPos = true;
            }

            else if ( xNeg){


                xNeg = false;
                yNeg = true;
            }

            else if(yPos){

                xNeg = true;
                yPos = false; 

            }

            else if (yNeg){

                yNeg = false;
                xPos = true;
            }
        }

        else if ( c == 'R'){

            if(xPos){

                xPos = false;
                yNeg = true;
            }

            else if ( xNeg){

                yPos = true;
                xNeg = false;
            }

            else if(yPos){

                yPos = false;
                xPos = true;
            }

            else if (yNeg){

                yNeg = false;
                xNeg = true;
            }

        }

        else if (c == 'F'){

            if(xNeg){

                initial[0]  -= 1;
            }

            else if (xPos){

                initial[0] += 1;
            }

            else if (yNeg){

                initial[1] -=1;
            }

            else if( yPos){

                initial[1] += 1;
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(initial));
}
```

The thing is I just don't the solution as it's feels ugly. Is there any better way 
to design the algorithm ?

Comment: First if this is a grid, the best solution is to have a 2D array one to represent columns(your forward direction) and the other to represent rows(you right/left)

Comment: The dimension of the Java array is fixed with the initialization, so, I assume it may not be the correct data-structure to handle this problem and will fail in large quantity of direction.

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes 'forward' in your application is a function of the previous move.
Forward simply means you repeat your last move.

If forward is your first move you need to pick a convention that says something like "Barbie is initially moving to the right".

Comment: I solved it, however, I appreciate some assistance for redesigning the algorithm.